# a Haskell function that converts a list of words to a string

Tags: string, list, haskell

For example:

```
wordsToString ["all","for","one","and","one","for","all"]
"all for one and one for all"
```

My code works without a type declaration:

```
wordsToString [] = ""
wordsToString [word] = word
wordsToString (word:words) = word ++ ' ':(wordsToString words)
```

But when I do the type check,it shows that it is a list of Chars which seems wrong to me as I'm supposed to declare the input as a list of strings and get a string as the output:

```
*Main> :type wordsToString
wordsToString :: [[Char]] -> [Char]
```

I want to change the declaration to `wordsToString::[(String)]->[String]` but it won't work

Comment: `String` is just a type alias of `[Char]`, which means they're _exactly_ the same type. What makes you think `[(String)] -> [String]` means "a list of strings and get a string as the output"?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to change the declaration to `wordsToString::[(String)]->[String]` but it won't work

No, you want to change the declaration to `wordsToString :: [String] -> String`. You aren't getting a list of strings out, just a single one.

Answer (score 1):

The function is called `concat`:

```
concat :: Foldable t => t [a] -> [a]
concat xs = foldr (++) [] xs
```

In your case, you want to insert a whitespace between the characters. This function is called `intercalate`:

```
intercalate :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]
```

It's defined in terms of `intersperse`.

Comment: As long as we're suggesting library functions, `unwords` seems like the closest fit.